# ListView with customized items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i have looked at the issue closely since you guys were so confident and i found that i have typed the incorrect layout name while i was typing in the question (sorry about that)

the correct contentview i have is this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

**End Edit**

i see my id in R.Java:

```
public static final int txtReadMore_link=0x7f06000e;
```

Update:

```
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.website.playlist_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at net.website.playlist_activity.onCreate(playlist_activity.java:101)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-19 17:05:07.158: E/AndroidRuntime(1356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

i am trying to access textview from the custom listview and below is the code and i am getting null ref error... how can i access to the `txtReadMore_link` ?

show the new activity when the user click on the link.

playlist_activity

```
private TextView link;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_row);

       //throwing error - NULL????
       link = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtReadMore_link);

       link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        TextView tx =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtReadMore_link); 
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(playlist_activity.this, tx.getText(), duration);
        toast.show();               
        }
    });
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"></ListView>    
</LinearLayout>
```

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!--  ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"      
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg" 
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView     
            android:id="@+id/list_image"   
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/rihanna"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Title Of Song-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Rihanna Love the way lie"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- Artist Name -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..." />


       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtReadMore_link"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_margin="5dp" 
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Click here to read more.."
            android:textSize="9sp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put your full logcat...?

Comment: see line no.101 in PlayListActivity.java,and see which one is?

Comment: i have updated my question again if you look at the very first line which i am getting a null exception and also while i do debugging i am getting null value `link = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtReadMore_link);', so my question is how can i access the textview?

Comment: clean your project and close unrelated project and rerun

Comment: Did you do fresh compile? Project clean?

Comment: yes i clean/clean-up/refresh but still the same and if i comment the above lines related with textview (link) then my app is working fine. i did debug and i am getting null reference for the `link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `findViewById()` from the `onCreate()` method to search for a `View` that is in a `ListView` row layout. The correct way is to use a custom adapter and in the `getView()` method set the on click listener for that particular `View`. There are many question around `StackOverflow` regarding how to do this. Here are some tutorials:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html or
http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf

Answer (score 1):

just clean your project and re run it like this : in your Eclipse IDE , click 
**Project ==> Clean ==> Check your Project ==> Press OK** . and Run again your project and it will works ;)

**EDIT :**

you have the `NullPointerException` because in your method `setContentView()` , you have specified the layout of your activity as : `main.xml`

And you are trying to find a `View` By id which is not in your layout `main.xml` ( it is on your `list_row.xml`)  , verify that you have specified the exact layout of your `Activity`, or try to declare your `TextView` in your layout `main.xml`

Comment: still the same and also i have updated my question, i see my id in the R.java file

Comment: also i deleted my R.java and its re-created - just fyi

Comment: in this case , normally if you have declared your View in the right layout , and you tried to find it after setting the contentView() , it should work, try to add another TextView and try to find it excatly the same way and see what happens , it's strange

Comment: i have updated my question the correct Contentview is setContentView(R.layout.main); not the `list_row`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not setting the view you think you are for your *activity*, i.e. you do

```
setContentView(R.layout.list_row);
```

in the onCreate, where you probably meant to say

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

As `txtReadMore_link` is on your `main.xml`, and not on your `list_row.xml`, the code will not be able to find the view and return null.

Comment: yes Paul that was typo on my end. so i will not able find? since i using a custom listview.. so in this situations what should be done?